# Рамка главного меню оставалась активной при переходе в submenu

Tags: html, css

```css
body { background-color: #17191b;}

nav {
 position: relative;
 top: 65px;
 left: -25px;
 margin: 0px;
 z-index: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 32px;
 width: 100%;
  background-color: #17191b;
}


ul {
 display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  }


ul.menu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Arial Bold', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 88px;
}

ul.menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #17191b;
  text-decoration: none;

}

ul.menu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #17191b;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


ul.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 305px;
  z-index: 15;

  top: 36px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;

}

ul.submenu>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #17191b;
  text-decoration: none;

}

ul.submenu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #17191b;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>ul.submenu {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТЬ</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
     <li><a href="transport.html">Транспорт и логистика</a></li>
     <li><a href="stroyka.html">Строительство и монтаж</a></li>
     <li><a href="trade.html">Оптово-розничная торговля</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="contact.html">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
   
   
   </ul>
     </nav>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно как на картинке:
сделать нижнюю рамку у родителя такого же цвета как фон при наведении, добавить у родительской ссылки z-index и высоту (в сумме с padding и border = 36px), чтобы точно перекрыть верхнюю рамку субменю:

```
ul.menu>li>a {
  position: relative;
  z-index:16;
  height:15px;
}
```

```css
body { background-color: #17191b;}

nav {
 position: relative;
 top: 65px;
 left: -25px;
 margin: 0px;
 z-index: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 32px;
 width: 100%;
  background-color: #17191b;
}


ul {
 display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  }


ul.menu>li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Arial Bold', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 88px;
}

ul.menu>li>a {
  position: relative;
  z-index:16;
  height:15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #17191b;
  text-decoration: none;

}

ul.menu>li:hover>a {
  background-color: #17191b;
  border: 1px solid #fff;

}
ul.menu>li:hover>a:not(:only-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #17191b;
}


ul.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 305px;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 36px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #fff;

}

ul.submenu>li {
  display: block;
}

ul.submenu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #17191b;
  text-decoration: none;

}

ul.submenu>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #17191b;
}

ul.menu>li:hover>ul.submenu {
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТЬ</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
     <li><a href="transport.html">Транспорт и логистика</a></li>
     <li><a href="stroyka.html">Строительство и монтаж</a></li>
     <li><a href="trade.html">Оптово-розничная торговля</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="contact.html">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>  
   
   </ul>
     </nav>
```

Comment: А вот как сделать, чтобы вот эта рамочка оставалась при переходе на нижние ссылки? Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: внесла правки, нужно hover на li  перевесить